# Is this a viable network configuration?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I live in a very strange and old house and wireless signal is having problems getting to where I want it to be available. So I envisioned this topology and wanted to run it by who know this stuff better than I do.

Here it is

```
AT&T Uverse GW (SSID: 2WIRExxx)
                  |
                  |
 +-----------+----+-----------+----------------+---------------+
 |           |                |                |               |
 (4)         computer         Computer         Security       PowerLine
 WiFi        (wired conn)     (wired conn)     Camera         Adapter
 Computers                                     Server          |
 SSID:2WIRExxx                                 (wired)         |
                                                               |
                                                       many, many walls
                                                         and corners   
                                                               |
                                                               |
                                                              PowerLine
                                                              Adapter
                                                               |
 +-----------+--------------+          +-----------------------+
 |           |              |          |
 Roku2       Computer       +----------Cisco
 Wired       Wired                     E-1200 (SSID:MyHome)
                                       |      (GuestSSID:MyHomeG)   
                                       |
                     +-----------------+----------------------+                
                     |            |              |            |
                     Tablet(s)    Cell           Roku2        Guests'       
                     SSID:MyHome  Phone(s)       WiFi         Wireless
                                  SSID:MyHome    SSID:MyHome  SSID:MyHomeG
```

Keep in mind, AT&T tech left the G/W at one cornerr of a garage conversion room with not much room to wiggle its location and I can connect to it wirelessly from 4 computers which are all set up in the office area I designated close to the gateway in the same room. The Cisco/Linksys device I have from my previous place, is going to be placed in the living room, where wireless signal is nearly non-existent (even a wireless signal extender can not operate) while the need for wireless operation is the most.

Will this topology work ?

Comment: You are aware of the gotchas when it comes to the Powerline Adapters right?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the multi circuit breaker homes but if there are any other "gotcha" points out there, I may not know them. Currently, the powelrline adapter is connected to the Roku2 (wired) unit onn the second tier of network I tried to draw above, directly, and it is working w/o any problems, streaming video from my local media server as well as netflix.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in theory, but as Ramhound mentioned, you'll need to test the powerline adapters and make sure they'll work.  Depending on how your home electrical is wired and configured, you may run into problems.  A big red flag would be if you have multiple breaker panels.  And since you mentioned it's an older home you may not get the maximum throughput depending on the condition of the wiring.

Ideally the Cisco device can be set to access-point only mode.  This way your U-verse router will still hand out IP addresses and the wireless clients won't get double NAT-ted.

But in the end the only way to find out is to try!  Good luck.

Comment: If I let my cisco unit, run in router mode instead of access point, how bad of a latency we are talking about here by double NAT'ing and are there any other disadvantages (other than speed I meant) to use double NAT'ing method ?

Comment: I don't think there will be any major impact on latency aside from one additional router hop.  The big drawbacks are A) devices behind the Cisco router won't be accessible by other devices in your home, B) managing two network ranges (the cisco can't use the same IP network as the U-verse router), and C) it just adds complexity and makes troubleshooting that much more difficult.

Comment: From what I'm reading on the Cisco/Linksys website, you should be able to set the E-1200 up as an access point only.  As Spiff mentioned below, the guest network functionality won't work how you intend it to.

Answer (score 0):

Your Guest Network plan won't work the way Guest SSIDs are usually intended to work. Usually, an AP (wireless router) with Guest SSID functionality needs to be the NAT gateway at the *head* of your network, so that the network out its WAN port is the public Internet, not another segment of your LAN. They work by making sure the Guest SSID traffic can get out the WAN port, but not to its own LAN ports or main SSID. But if you have another segment of your home LAN out its WAN port, those devices will be accessible to the guests just like anything else on the Internet.

In your proposed topology, everything between your Cisco/Linksys E1200 and your AT&T U-verse 2Wire box will be accessible to your guests.

All of Apple's AirPort base stations that support Guest Networks, which means all the simultaneous dual band equipment, which means all Extremes and Time Capsules since 2009 or so, as well as the 2012 AirPort Express, can now, as of a firmware update in 2012 or 2013, support "Guest Network Extension" where remote units (in place of your E1200 is) can publish a guest network, and tunnel it in a VLAN to the main unit (in place of your AT&T U-verse 2Wire box), to make sure the guest network traffic gets out to the Internet without being able to access the LAN devices in between. To use that, you'd want to configure your 2Wire box to just act as a transparent modem (NAT off, DHCP service off, wireless off), and have your AirPort Extreme's WAN port plugged in as the only thing on the 2Wire box's LAN port. Also replace your E1200 with another AirPort Extreme.